# how to convert .cdr (corel draw file) vector images to jpg on imagick PHP API

Tags: php, api, image

how to convert .cdr (corel draw file) vector images to jpg on imagick PHP API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried this, but I think your best bet is the intermediate step of [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

Corel Draw -> Scalable Vector Graphics -> JPEG

CDR->SVG appears to be possible with [UniConvertor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor)

> Supported Corel filetypes = CorelDRAW
>   ver.7-X3,X4 (CDR/CDT/CCX/CDRX/CMX)

SVG->JPG convertion may be done via [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php)